# save an image field from django template to a table

Tags: python, django

I have a form in my template like this :

```
   <form action="." method="GET" style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 12px">
         <table style="width: 100%;">
             <tr>
                 <td>
                     name: 
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     <input id="name" name="name" type="text"/>
                 </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td>
                     <label>capacity :</label>&nbsp;</td>
                 <td>
                     <input id="capacity" name="capacity" type="text" />
                 </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td>
                     <label>picture:</label>
                 </td>
                 <td>    
                     <input type="file" name="imageName_1" id="1"/></a>
                     </div>
                 </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td>
                    &nbsp;
                 </td>
                 <td>
                    <input id="add" type="button" value="save"/>
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
 </form>
```

I wanna get 2 fields and an image then save them into below model:

```
class Tour(models.Model):
   Name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
   capacity=models.SmallIntegerField() 
   image=models.ImageField(upload_to="gallery")
```

how can I save this image from my template via a view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you having a specific problem with the way django explains how to do this? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/

First of all, you need to assign `enctype="multipart/form-data"` inside the `<form>` tag.

If you must do this manually instead of leveraging the power of Django's forms framework, you need to manually assign the file / field data to your model.

```
def myview(request):
    image = request.FILES['imageName_1'] 
    tour = Tour()
    tour.Name = request.POST.get('name')
    tour.capacity = request.POST.get('capacity')
    tour.image.save(image.name, image)
    tour.save()
```

I'd recommend checking out django's ModelForms as a view / template combo that does this and much more (error checking / redisplaying) can be written in one minute.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = Tour

def myview(self):     
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = MyForm()
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', {'form': form})


<form method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I wanna user can enter at most 5 Images for each Tour,I used javascript in my template,when user select a picture it automatically add another input file,while he at most enter 5 Images,How can I implement this while I'm using ModelForms?

Comment: Your model only supports one image per Tour. If you had another Model that was (many to one) related to Tour, you would use a `FormSet`, another powerful form tool. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#formsets

Comment: sorry I'm new in django and I have a strange question! where should I define my modelForms?I put it in models.py but it has error!in documention I didn't find where to define modelForms

Comment: ModelForms? That would most likely be defined in your `views.py` for a simple app. As an app got bigger, it might be defined in a `forms.py`